# What is polkitd doing when it is pinning 2 out of 4 CPUs for many hours?

Tags: polkit

I run a park of machines for a charity and do not get paid for this. We have a zoo of various OSs running on machines donated by sponsors. They are wiped clean and installed what is best expected to run on them. Among these machines there is about 1000 Fedora linux boxes which I am gradually migrating from Fedora 15-20 to 27-28.

All of the Fedora 27 / 28 boxes experience the same problem: every few days `polkitd` pins 1 CPU out of 2 or 2 CPUs out of 4. I have not found any helpful information on what specifically `polkitd` could be doing in this case. What might be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you are under Fedora, move the file `org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.DiskUtilityNotify.desktop` out of `/etc/xdg/autostart` or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

PolicyKit reads various directories.  If the attempts to read return an error, it attempts them again repeatedly.  I have observed this as one way in which PolicyKit can consume CPU time, fixable by making the directories exist and accessible to account under whose aegis the PolicyKit process is running.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  "[The PolicyKit service](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/services/polkitd.html)".  [nosh *Guide*](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/).  Softwares.